# Haskell - MinMax using foldr

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a Haskell function that takes a list as an argument and returns a tuple (min, max), where min is the minimal value of the list and max is the maximal value.

I already have this:

```
maxMinFold :: Ord a => [a] -> (a, a)
maxMinFold list = foldr (\x (tailMin, tailMax) -> (min x tailMin) (max x tailMax)) -- missing part
```

Could you help me what to add to the missing part? (or tell me what I am doing wrong)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You take the head and use that as the fist min **and** max and then fold over the tail.

```
maxMinFold :: Ord a => [a] -> (a, a)
maxMinFold (x:xs) = foldr (\x (tailMin, tailMax) -> (min x tailMin, max x tailMax)) (x,x) xs
```

As regards your answer, your fold function is not returning the right type.

Note that

```
foldr :: (a -> b **-> b**) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

In particular you need to be returning a `b`, which is a tuple in your case

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Just a question - why this does not work?
`maxMinFold list = foldr (\x (tailMin, tailMax) -> (min x tailMin) (max x tailMax)) (head list, head list) list`

Comment: `(min x tailMin) (max x tailMax)` is not something that has a Type, let alone a tuple Type. I added a bit more to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since you always have to traverse the whole list to find the minimum and the maximum here is the solution with `foldl`:

```
maxMinList :: Ord a => [a] -> (a,a)
maxMinList (x:xs) = foldl (\(l,h) y -> (min l y, max h y)) (x,x) xs
```

Comment: ... and `let ma = min l y; mb = max h y in ma ´seq´ mb ´seq´ (ma,mb)`

Comment: As long as we're being pedantic, there are some types for which you don't have to traverse the whole list, specifically types which have a minimum and/or maximum element.

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently with `foldr`,

```
data NEList a = NEList a [a]
-- deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

minMax :: Ord a => NEList -> (a, a)
minMax (NEList x0 xs) = foldr go (,) xs x0 x0 where
  go x r mn mx
    | x < mn = r x mx
    | mx < x = r mn x
    | otherwise = r mn mx
```

Another, similar, approach:

```
minMaxM :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe (a, a)
minMaxM xs = foldr go id xs Nothing where
  go x r Nothing = r (Just (x, x))
  go x r mnmx@(Just (mn, mx))
    | x < mn = r (Just (x, mx))
    | mx < x = r (Just (mn, x))
    | otherwise = r mnmx
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the `minMax` function returned `Nothing` in the case of an empty list. Here is a version which does that.

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Foldable

minMax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe (a,a)
minMax = foldl' (flip $ \ x -> Just . maybe (x,x) (min x *** max x)) Nothing
```

This uses `foldl'` instead of `foldr`.